# Visual Studio 2013 Compilation Error - Code not detected properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Having a very odd issue with Visual Studio 2013, curious if anyone else is seeing anything similar.  I have VS 2013 Ultimate, it seems like once a day, while I'm working with a file, the compiler just suddenly freaks out and doesn't detect my code anymore in my web forms.  Take a look at the screenshot below (I just chose a random spot in the middle of the web form), but out of nowhere, VS starts erroring, telling me that variables aren't declared, that method arguments need parenthesis on lines of code that aren't methods, all sorts of whacky stuff.

I assure you, I don't have any broken references, I didn't forget to close an if statement.. nothing like that.  All I'm doing it writing some code, and randomly the whole page just starts to error like this.  To resolve, all I can do is copy the code contents, delete the page, recreate the page, and paste the contents back into my "new" file... same exact code, only no errors.  I wouldn't even worry about doing this if I wasn't doing this at least once a day.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: For what it's worth, I found a slightly easier workaround for this issue.  If I edit the properties of the class file to "Do not Compile" and then back to "Compile", the IDE is able to read the file just fine...

[image: My errors in Visual Studio]

Comment: I have seen this, or something very similar, occasionally in VS2010. I found that going to the first 'error' and re-arranging the white space around it - couple of newlines, etc would force it to refresh its view of the code and bring it back to normal.

Comment: Thanks @peterG I'll give that a shot next time and will let you know if that resolves!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is simply a bug in the Vb.Net Compiler / IDE.  I agree it's unlikely to be a bug in your code because you can see that the error squiggles don't line up with places that would represent the errors you are reporting.  This is sometimes a sign of an IDE bug

In terms of fixing the problem though you can probably get them to go away by closing and reopening the solution in question.  Baring that restarting Visual Studio.  I wouldn't resort to deleted / recreating the page.

Long term though you may want to file an issue on connect so the IDE team can try and fix the problem.

> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: Thanks Jared, I have tried Clean\Rebuild and closing\opening VS in the past, and unfortunately that doesn't do it.  I should also add, this issue occurs on both class and web form code behinds (should probably just add that above..)  Anyway, thanks for the link, I'll send something to MS.

Comment: @ewitkows if it doesn't fix itself on reopen then it may not be a bug. Have you tried putting your project in source control and diffing everything when the problem shows up?  It may reveal a subtle change that is affecting the code

Comment: Because I haven't done anything that I thought would constitute the entire file having an error, I haven't done that.  However it's probably not a bad exercise to undertake just incase there's a bad space in the file, etc.  I see the errors throughout the entire file, even in the class declaration itself, but I'll give this a shot next time the error occurs.  Thanks again @Jared